# Proceed to next step only when function has been run 10 times

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, rxjs

I have this function:

```
function setIntervalX(callback, delay, repetitions): Promise<any> {

  let promises = [];

  var x = 0;
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
  callback();
    if (++x === repetitions) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalID);
      promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {});
    }
   }, delay);
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

My goal is to call a function in test and the after those 10 calls have ended, I want to call expect in my function. So that means I have to wait for it to end, like this:

```
setIntervalX(() => {

     //logic here

     }, 1000, 10).then(() => {
                  expect(something).toBe(anotherThing);
                  });
```

I feel that my way of doing this is ugly, and can be done bettery. Any suggestions?

Comment: ok, I reformatted it, will you help now :) ?

Comment: With respect, but look at the above. Would you really call that "consistently and readably" formatted? `callback` is misaligned in the first code block, which is misleading; that first block also still features inconsistent indentation in other ways; and the less said about the second code block the better. Making your post and code clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: If this is a test, why are you spacing them out with a 1 second interval instead of just running them back to back? It's also not clear from your question whether `callback` may return a promise, i.e. effectively represents an asynchronous operation, and whether it takes less than a second to execute (meaning the tests execute in sequence), or more (they end up executing concurrently i.e. in parallel). Clarifying this might make it a better question.

Comment: What do you mean by "calls have ended"? If you're just trying to resume after the 10th call has been fired off, then `setTimeout(something, 10000)` would seem to suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need the individual promises (you never use them above except in `Promise.all`), just use a single promise:

```
function setIntervalX(callback, delay, repetitions): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let x = 0;
        let intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
            callback();
            if (++x === repetitions) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalID);
                resolve();
            }
        }, delay);
    });
}
```

Comment: great, but it is still not elegant and could be done better ?

Comment: @JerzyGruszka: Other than removing the unnecessary `window.` on the timer functions, I'm not sure what else you'd do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this fails to propagate errors correctly if callback() throws or returns a rejected promise.

Comment: @jib: I was just addressing the actual question, not doing a code review.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged RxJS as well so I'll throw out an Rx solution.

```
function setIntervalX(callback, delay, repetitions): Observable<any> {
  //Emit an event every delay
  return Rx.Observable.interval(delay)
    //Only accept a certain number of events
    .take(repetitions)
    // Process the callback each time
    .do(() => callback())
    // Convert the result into a promise
    .toPromise();
}

setIntervalX(() => {
  //logic here  
}, 1000, 10)
.then(() => {                
  expect(something).toBe(anotherThing);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a more elegant solution, how's this:

```js
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let setIntervalX = (cb, delay, reps) =>
  Promise.all(Array(reps).fill().map((n, i) => wait(delay * (i + 1)).then(cb)));

// Demo:

let test = () => Promise.resolve().then(() => (console.log("test"), "!"));

setIntervalX(test, 1000, 10).then(results => console.log(results.join("")));
```

I interpret the code in your question as wanting to support promise-returning `callback`s. This supports that, and also propagates errors correctly, which is hard to do with `setInterval`.

The `setInterval` and `setTimeout` APIs have terrible error handling characteristics on their own, and are best wrapped tightly in tiny promise returning functions, never to be called directly again.

Note that for high values of `repetitions` this isn't particularly efficient.